# How to obtain a bigint from a date?

Tags: presto

Running it

`SELECT timestamp '2019-6-2 00:00 UTC'`

will return a date representation to me

[image]

then I want to obtain it as a bigint,

`SELECT cast(timestamp '2019-6-2 00:00 UTC' as bigint)`

I got this error

`Query failed (#20190604_014249_16755_mru2t): line 1:8: Cannot cast timestamp with time zone to bigint`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What bigint do you want?  One reasonable answer is a unix timestamp:

```
select cast(to_unixtime(timestamp '2019-6-2 00:00 UTC') as bigint)
```